# Having trouble hiding a div when other elements are chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, blur

I am using the below javascript to hide a div when a button state selection is chosen but I am using this code on a Content Management System. The code works but only after I reload the page (after I make the correct selection). I believe that something may be off with the way I am using blur and change. I believe that may be the key to making the change update live without a reload but I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
var choice = $('#Choice').val();  
var myDiv = $('#myDiv');  

if(choice == 'Option 1'){  
  $(myDiv).hide().blur().change();  
} else {  
  $(myDiv).show().blur().change();  
}
```

Below is the code for the button I am targeting:

Option 1
  
    Option 2

Comment: Please provide more context about your situation. When is the code you've shown being executed (part of an event handler)? Also, include the relevant HTML.

Comment: It is not a part of an event handler. I was not sure if there was an event handler that could help with what I need. The 'choice' variable is a button with multiple options that when chosen would hide the myDiv div. Eventually I will have other variables that I will need added to that one (radio buttons, not button states) that will need to be chosen at all to hide that div. But I am starting with just the first option to see how I can get the change to communicate with the server. The code provided is not in a function or event handler because it does need to be within the CMS.

Comment: So why not just set up a `change` event handler on the element that has the choices? Where is this code in the larger document? When does it run? Please show the relevant HTML.

Comment: Also I will need the option to be a specific choice within the button options. Change will only work for any option choice, correct?

Comment: Before we can provide any more specifics, you really need to edit your question, add the relevant HTML and answer my other questions: Where is the code you've shown inserted within your larger JavaScript? When does it run?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you need to do is simply set up a `change` event handler for your `select` element. Then, within that handler, just check the selection - - if it's what you care about, hide the `div`, if not, show it. There is no need for you to cause `blur` or `change` to occur, since the user will do that for you.

Here's an example:

```js
$("select").on("change", function(){
  if(this.value === "Choice 2"){
    $("div").hide();
  } else {
    $("div").show();  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option>Choice 1</option>
  <option>Choice 2</option>
  <option>Choice 3</option>
</select>

<div>I will hide when Choice 2 is selected and show otherwise</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some misunderstandings about some of jQuery's methods. You probably want this:

```
const myDiv = $('#myDiv');  

$('#Choice').change(function() {

    const choice = $(this).val();
    
    if (choice === 'Option 1') {  
        myDiv.hide();  
    } else {  
        myDiv.show();  
    }

});
```

I'm not sure what your button "state" is, so this may need adjustment after you show us what you're doing with that.

Comment: That worked well. Thanks so much. Do you know how I may detect if a value is supplied for a radio button? I need to make sure that a button has a value at all. I am guessing I can maybe do it by detecting a length for the value.

Comment: No problem. Please take the [tour]. New questions are not appropriate in comments.

Comment: @tmd257 All HTML form input elements hold strings, to check to see if an element has no value you need to check to see if there is no string. That is done by checking for `""` (an empty string).